# How is `ghc Main.hs` different from `ghc --make Main.hs`?

Tags: ghc

I see the [documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/5.02/docs/set/make-mode.html) on `ghc`'s `--make`, however I do not understand how running `ghc` with `--make` is any different from running it without that option.

To investigate, I created these modules `Main` and `Dependency`:

```
module Main where

import Dependency ( myNumber )

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print "running program"
  print myNumber
  print "terminating program"
```

and

```
module Dependency where

myNumber :: Integer
myNumber = 42
```

From the directory containing these modules, I ran both `ghc Main.hs` and `ghc --make Main.hs`. Though the two commands wrote different messages while running, both worked successfully and produced the same output files.

```
$ ghc Main.hs 
[1 of 2] Compiling Dependency       ( Dependency.hs, Dependency.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )
Linking Main ...

$ ls
Dependency.hi  Dependency.hs  Dependency.o  Main  Main.hi  Main.hs  Main.o
```

and

```
$ ghc --make Main.hs 

$ ls
Dependency.hi  Dependency.hs  Dependency.o  Main  Main.hi  Main.hs  Main.o
```

What, if anything, does the `--make` option do that's different from what `ghc` does without it?

Comment: Does having a look at the next page in the documentation (ghc without --make) answer your question?